# error python console in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I get this error in PyCharm console. How do I correct this?

```
 C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.5.3\helpers\pydev\pydev_import_hook.py:21: RemovedInDjango19Warning: The utilities in django.db.models.loading are deprecated in favor of the new application loading system.
  module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. It is a built in warning telling you that a piece of functionality in Django will deprecated in version 1.9. So avoid using it if you plan on upgrading to 1.9

If you are really intent on fixing it, follow the deprecation warning and don't use the aforementioned module. The issue is that it may be used in a module you loaded and therefore out of your control.

Comment: OK Thank you @Incognos